# Not able to fetch row Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch mysql query row, however getting

> Fatal error:Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean.

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
$select="visitor_country";
$startDate="2016-01-01";
$endDate="2016-12-31";
$groupBy="visitor_country";

$query=$connection->prepare("SELECT ?, COUNT(*) as count FROM `analytics`.`analytics` WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ? ORDER BY count");
$query->bind_param('ssss',$select,$startDate,$endDate,$select);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->store_result();
$row = $result->fetch_row();

$num_of_rows=count($row);
echo $num_of_rows."<br>";
$query->close();
$connection->close();
```

Comment: `store_result()` returns a boolean true/false, so that's not surprising. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php

Comment: @Qirel even if I remove store_result() I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I think what you want is `$result = $query->get_result()` instead? This transforms it from a MySQLi stmt to a MySQLi result, which you can use `fetch_row()` on. [Manual for `get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php). Also, both MySQLi stmt and MySQLi result comes with a `num_rows` property, so instead of `count($row)` you can do `$query->num_rows`

Comment: Found the error

Comment: So it was to use `get_result()` like I suggested? ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But I have a bit of more problem. Care to look at it?

Comment: Sure thing. :-) just give a description of the issue

Comment: I have re-edited the post. Please go through with it and let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer

```
$query->bind_param('ssss',$select,$startDate,$endDate,$select);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$num_of_rows=count($row);
echo $num_of_rows."<br>";
$query->close();
$connection->close();
```